# Simplify the fraction $\frac{(a \times b) ⋅ (a \times b)}{(c \times b) ⋅ (c \times b)}$

Tags: linear-algebra

I have vectors $a$, $b$ and $c$ in $\mathbb R^3$. Can I simplify the following fraction:

$$\frac{(a \times b) ⋅ (a \times b)}{(c \times b) ⋅ (c \times b)}$$

I tried expressing it in terms of Lagrange's identity but I'm not getting anywhere:
$$\frac{(a \times b) ⋅ (a \times b)}{(c \times b) ⋅ (c \times b)} = \frac{||a||^2 \cdot ||b||^2-(a \cdot b)^2}{||c||^2 \cdot ||b||^2-(c \cdot b)^2}$$

I'm guessing that to simplify this we need to express this fraction in terms of the individual components of the three vectors? What would that fraction look like?

Comment: So is $a \times b$ the cross product?

Comment: @TobyMak Yes it is

Comment: See [Equation of dot product and cross product](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2863194/equation-of-dot-product-and-cross-product): the numerator is $(a \cdot a)(b \cdot b) - (a \cdot b)(b \cdot a)$ as a special case of the Binet-Cauchy identity.

Comment: @TobyMak I already expressed it similarly using Lagrange's identity. But I can't still simplify the fraction $\frac{(a⋅a)(b⋅b)−(a⋅b)(b⋅a)}{(c⋅c)(b⋅b)−(c⋅b)(b⋅c)}$